# Hazelcast instance becomes inactive (HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException)

Tags: hazelcast

Looking at the Hazelcast source code (version 3.2.6), it appears that the only way that a Hazelcast node can spontaneously become inactive and start throwing HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException - other than an application-initiated shutdown, of course - is an out-of-memory condition.

Is that correct? Or are there any other reasons?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are other reasons, but an OOME can certainly lead to a HazelcastInstance shutdown.

If you are running low on memory (70% or more used), the Hazelcast Healthmonitor should start kicking in and should show you periodically all kinds of metrics. Can you check your logging?

We normally run our performance/stress tests with:

`-verbosegc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:gc.log`

This way we can see what is happening on the gc level.

PS: It is impossible for HZ to trap all OOME, so we can only see the ones that happen internally; as soon as it is detected the HazelcastInstance is shut down.